# jssor: Is there a way to preload last-in-the-sequence image when using lazy-loading?

Tags: lazy-loading, jssor

The "[Nearby image partially visible](http://www.jssor.com/demos/nearby-image-partial-visible-slider.slider)" demo of Jssor shows 3 images at once. The first in the sequence is displayed in the middle, the next on the right-hand side, and the last in the sequence is on the left-hand side. Now, when I activate lazy loading, the slider is displayed, however only 2 of the images are visible. The one on the left gets not read (*yet*, obviously because only the first `n` images are loaded, set by `$LazyLoading` parameter). Is it possible to somehow force Jssor to load the last image at the start, too? (The workaround would be to start with the index 1 instead of 0 (`$StartIndex` parameter), however I don't want this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug, I have just fixed it. Please download the latest version.

Comment: Great, now works like a charm! Thank you very much. (By the way, please update also the debug version, that one seems to be not fixed yet)